# Accessing old / new site at the same time using hosts file

Tags: terminal, dns, hosts, hosts-file

This is an odd request, but one I can't get my head around. We are currently building a new site on a new server, but don't want to update the DNS settings until it's ready to go, since we need a live, working site. In order to gain access to this to build it, I changed my hosts file (in Terminal) so that it would pull from that IP. Example

00.000.000.000 mywebsite.com [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)

The problem is, I need to import images from the old site into the new site, but since I have the hosts file setup it's not able to pull it. Any ideas of a workaround? I have multiple computers, but it needs to be done on the same computer since I need access to the backend of the new site at the exact same time of the old site, so that it can pull that image over.

Comment: What client/tool are you using to pull and upload images?

Comment: It's a Wordpress plugin